# How do I use the Riding data tag in Minecraft 1.10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to summon a mob riding another in my Minecraft 1.10 server. A villager riding a bat to be specific. But if I use `/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat"}}` it doesn't work. it just spawns the villager.
What command can I use to spawn a villager riding a bat in a bukkit 1.10 server?

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I've found by looking at commands, I think you want to do

```
/summon Bat ~ ~ ~ {Passengers[{id:"Villager"}]}
```

That will summon a farmer riding on a bat. If you want to do things like giving the villager trades or changing his profession, [mcstacker.bimbimma.com](http://mcstacker.bimbimma.com) will probably help.